# How might I optimize these two mutually recursive functions in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, math

I have to write methods that sum and provide lists of the outputs of these composite mutually recursive functions, but their execution keeps timing out with my current implementation:

```
public static long fAnn(long n) {
      if (n == 0) return 1;
      else return n - fJohn(fAnn(n-1));
    }

    public static long fJohn(long n) {
      if (n <= 0) return 0;
      else return n - fAnn(fJohn(n-1));
    }
public static List<Long> john(long n) {
    List<Long> res = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      res.add(fJohn(i));
    }

    return res;       
}

public static long sumJohn(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += fJohn(i);
    return sum;
}
public static long sumAnn(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += fAnn(i);
    return sum;
}
```

I've thought of passing the last value of the function back to the function, but I'm not really sure how I could do that.

Comment: If your current implementation is broken, then I'd say you should fix that first, then come back here if you need help with a refactor.

Comment: I didn't understand the purpose of these two functions. Can you clarify it a little more, and how these functions are called?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the current implementation works fine for numbers less than a million but i don't understand how to optimize it for all long numbers

Comment: Google "Fibnoacci sequence dynamic programming" ... if someone here solves this for you, you'll learn very little from this assignment

Comment: @GhostCat gotcha! i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice of @Tim Beigeleisen and decided to learn more about dynamic programming to improve the naive recursive approach I took to this function instead of looking for answers here first.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Johnann {
    private static Map<Long, Long> jMem;
    private static Map<Long, Long> aMem;


    public static long fAnn(long n) {
      if (n < 2) {
        aMem = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
        aMem.put(n, (long)1);
        return 1;
      }
      else if (aMem.keySet().contains(n)) {
        return aMem.get(n);
      }
      else {
        long res = n - fJohn(fAnn(n-1));
        aMem.put(n, res);
        return res;
      }
    }


    public static long fJohn(long n) {
      if (n < 2) {
        jMem = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
        jMem.put(n, (long)0);
        return 0;
      }
      else if (jMem.keySet().contains(n)) {
        return jMem.get(n);
      }
      else {
        long res = n - fAnn(fJohn(n-1));
        jMem.put(n, res);
        return res;
      }
    }

    public static List<Long> john(long n) {
        List<Long> res = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          res.add(fJohn(i));
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static List<Long> ann(long n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        List<Long> res = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          res.add(fAnn(i));
        }

        return res;
    }


    public static long sumJohn(long n) {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n < 2) return 1;
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += fJohn(i);
        return sum;
    }
    public static long sumAnn(long n) {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n < 2) return 1;
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += fAnn(i);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I saw other, better implementations that used an ArrayList instead of a map, for instance:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Johnann {

    private enum Person {JOHN, ANN}

    private static List<Long> getListForName(Person person, long n) {
        List<Long> ann = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1L));
        List<Long> john = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0L));

        for (int dayAnn = 1, dayJohn = 1; dayAnn < n || dayJohn < n; ) {
            if (john.size() > ann.get(dayAnn - 1)) {
                ann.add(dayAnn - john.get(Math.toIntExact(ann.get(dayAnn - 1))));
                dayAnn++;
            }
            if (ann.size() > john.get(dayJohn - 1)) {
                john.add(dayJohn - ann.get(Math.toIntExact(john.get(dayJohn - 1))));
                dayJohn++;
            }
        }
        return (person == Person.JOHN ? john : ann).subList(0, Math.toIntExact(n));
    }

    public static List<Long> john(long n) {
        return getListForName(Person.JOHN, n);
    }

    public static List<Long> ann(long n) {
        return getListForName(Person.ANN, n);
    }

    public static long sumJohn(long n) {
        return john(n).stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
    }

    public static long sumAnn(long n) {
        return ann(n).stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
    }
}
```

This was probably way faster, but I'm just happy that I learned a lot about dynamic programming and optimizing recursive calls through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution is executing methods with the same arguments a great number of times. Instead of doing so you can use an optimization technique called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

From Wikipedia:

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

An implementation may look like this. Note that this time you'll need to create a class instance to use the methods because they are no longer static.

```
private Map<Long, Long> annCache = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Long, Long> johnCache = new HashMap<>();

long fAnn2(long n) {
    return annCache.computeIfAbsent(n, x -> {
        if (x == 0) return 1L;
        else return x - fJohn2(fAnn2(x - 1));
    });
}

long fJohn2(long n) {
    return johnCache.computeIfAbsent(n, x -> {
        if (x <= 0) return 0L;
        else return x - fAnn2(fJohn2(x - 1));
    });
}
```